# Binary Code Generator Matrix (20, 10 or 11)

Tags: coding-theory

According to [this page](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/binary-1.html), there should be a code of length 20 with hamming distance 6 and between 2048-2279 codewords (or in other words, that contains at least $2^{11}$ words, meaning that data with 11 bits could be transmitted within blocks of 20 with HD 6).

Where or how do I find the generator matrix? Would I be able to detect how many errors happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator matrix is only for linear codes, that page is for general codes.

For linear binary codes, according to [this table](http://www.codetables.de/BKLC/Tables.php?q=2&n0=1&n1=256&k0=1&k1=256), $d=5$ is the most you can get for $n=20$, $k=11$

Comment: Even so.. where can I find such a generator matrix? is it even known?

Comment: I do not understand this 100% yet, but [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X04000597) seems to say that there are several `[20,10,6]` codes.

Comment: @Daniel Go here http://www.codetables.de/BKLC/index.html  This will give you the generator matrix for linear (20,10,6) and (20,11,5)  codes